# How to keep Activity reference in all fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, reference

How to keep track of the MainActivity reference in each fragment? In my project I need to `getAssets()` from nested Fragment and `getActivity()` returns **null**. In *MainActivity* where have a container for 2 fragments, one of them creates another fragment and there I don't have the *MainActivity* reference. How to use it there?

Comment: Pretty sure you can not have a `Fragment` without attaching it to an `Activity`.

Comment: @MuratK. I know it, I have got only one Activity in my project and the fragments, in the first two fragments which are created in Activity I got the reference. But in the rest (which are created within one of those 2 fragments) I don't. I printed it on the screen: it's null.

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: maybe it's gotta something to do with the lifecycle phase you're trying to get the activity. must be after the `onAttach()` is called

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks for showing me the root of it. I tried to use getActivity() before the fragment was actually created.